# C# - Creating IIS user programmatically

Tags: iis

I've developed an application for creating and managing FTP site and IIS users.

There is a method to create IIS user:

```
   public static void CreateIisUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var config = serverManager.GetAdministrationConfiguration();
            var authenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/management/authentication");
            var credentialsCollection = authenticationSection.GetCollection("credentials");

            var exist = credentialsCollection.Any(m => (string)m["name"] == userName);

            if (exist)
            {
                return;
            }

            var addElement = credentialsCollection.CreateElement("add");
            addElement["name"] = userName;
            addElement["password"] = password;
            addElement["enabled"] = true;
            credentialsCollection.Add(addElement);

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
```

It's works, but I don't have an access to FTP folder because of incorrect password.

Changing the password of the user via IIS Manager helps me.

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the password should be hashed in some way?

Comment: Yes, password should be encypted with SHA-256.

Answer (score 1):

Password should be encrypted with SHA-256:

```
        public static string HashSha256(string value)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var hash = SHA256Managed.Create())
        {
            var enc = Encoding.UTF8;
            var result = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(value));

            foreach (var b in result)
            {
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            }
        }

        var hashSha256 = sb.ToString().ToUpper();

        return hashSha256;
    }
```